# Autocomplete in blockly text

Tags: blockly, google-blockly

I'm just starting into blockly. I have seen that you can ask inputs to the users with a js popup. Is there a way of providing the users with more complex selectors such as an autocomplete textfield? For the moment, calling a jquery and getting the value should be enough, such as

```
  $( function() {
var availableTags = [
  "aaa",
  "bbb",
  "ccc",
  "ddd"
];
$( "#tags" ).autocomplete({
  source: availableTags
});
});
```

(this is an example, any other available js autocomplete library is ok)